# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, autocomplete

I'm using the JQuery UI autocomplete for quite a few text fields on my Backbone.js project. The libraries are loaded in the correct order as follows,

```
define(['jquery','jquery-ui.min','jquery.ui.touch-punch']);
```

The autocomplete function gets called, like so:

```
$("#channelRspm").autocomplete({
 minLength: 3,
 delay: 1000,
 source: function(request, response) {
 var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(channel, request.term);
 response(results.slice(0, 10));
   }
});
```

The problem is that the autocomplete behavior is very random. When running the source on Chrome browser, sometimes it works flawlessly. However, sometimes I get the error in console :
    Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

Refreshing the html normally makes it work again but then, that is not what I want. Could anyone please suggest where I'm going worng?

Comment: Sounds like the jQuery ui library is not loading

Comment: When do you call the `autocomplete`? In document.ready? Because the document should be ready with jQuery ui fully loaded.

Comment: Yes, the 'autocomplete' gets called in document.ready(). The loading of source json array and calling autocomplete on the source, both happen inside document.ready().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure [jquery-ui](/questions/tagged/jquery-ui) is loaded after [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) using `shim`.

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    "jquery": "lib/jquery",
    "jquery-ui": "lib/jquery-ui",
    "underscore": "lib/underscore",
    "backbone": "lib/backbone"
  },
  shim: {
    "underscore": {
        exports: "_"
    },
    "backbone": {
        exports: "Backbone",
        deps: ["underscore", "jquery"]
    },
    "jquery-ui": {
        exports: "$",
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
  }
});
```

You need to specify `jquery-ui` as dependency for `jquery.ui.touch-punch` in similar way.

then define your module like

```
define(['jquery','jquery-ui','jquery.ui.touch-punch']);
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped save a few hours of my day.